# Pushing Spring boot app to heroku not completed

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, heroku

when I'm deploying my simple project to Heroku I'm getting a maven-plugin error
[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHpeN.png)

my code is very simple it's one entity class and restController class, when I run my project on my pc it working but the deployment failed.
my class

```
package com.hosting.hostingTest;

public class BucketList {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public BucketList(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

my rest controller

```
package com.hosting.hostingTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;



@RestController
public class BucketListController {

    private List<BucketList> myBucketList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    public BucketListController(){
        myBucketList.add(new BucketList(counter.incrementAndGet(), "Visit Colosseum in Rome"));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity index() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myBucketList);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/bucket")
    public ResponseEntity getBucket(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
        BucketList itemToReturn = null;
        for(BucketList bucket : myBucketList){
            if(bucket.getId() == id)
                itemToReturn = bucket;
        }

        if(itemToReturn == null){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("No bucket found with id " + id);
        }else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(itemToReturn);
        }

    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity addToBucketList(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
        myBucketList.add(new BucketList(counter.incrementAndGet(), name));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myBucketList);
    }

    @PutMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity updateBucketList(@RequestParam(value="name") String name, @RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
        myBucketList.forEach(bucketList ->  {
            if(bucketList.getId() == id){
                bucketList.setName(name);
            }
        });
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myBucketList);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity removeBucketList(@RequestParam(value="id") Long id) {
        BucketList itemToRemove = null;
        for(BucketList bucket : myBucketList){
            if(bucket.getId() == id)
                itemToRemove = bucket;
        }

        myBucketList.remove(itemToRemove);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(myBucketList);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hosting</groupId>
    <artifactId>hostingTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hostingTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the error :

```
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /tmp/build_a3c8365b/target/classes
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  10.228 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-12T12:41:17Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project hostingTest: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Can you post the complete Heroku build output as text? I suspect the underlying issue to be printed in the logs that are not visible in your screenshot.

Comment: I did @Malax , this is the only error that showing in the logs in heroku site